# How the operation of .jar to .exe works?

Tags: java, exe

You know the jar to exe programs that compile a java project into .exe I want to know how such software actually work.

What is the method they follow to do this operation?

Do they change the bytecode of the jar file into exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two at least two approaches that result in an .exe file the user can click.

The simpler one is *wrapping* the required java environment and the exe only acts as a launcher for a standard VM. A JRE may be included into the wrapped application or alternately a system installed JRE may be used. launch4j (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) is an example that works in this manner.

Its also possible to do the work of the JIT (producing native code the CPU can execute) independently and ahead of deployment. There is (was?) gcj (https://gcc.gnu.org/java/) and at least one commercial product exists (Excelsior JET) that provides this capability.

As for your question "how": Wrapping does not change the code, it just provides a launcher that sets up the necessary environment for the java code to run, automating the process to the point where the end user does not need to know that they're running java code. This may be combined with any installer package to provide a care-free "click to install" and "click to run" user experience (e.g. InnoSetup).

The compiling to native code does basically the same as any other compiler, translate input language to native code. Due to many of javas features that are runtime-dynamic (e.g. classloading, reflection) this requires quite some effort to translate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the executable is just launching your jar. It's still bytecode and still runs in JVM.

Comment: Your jar will be packaged inside the executable file. Think of it as a archive. Alongside with the jar there is a launcher that calls system calls to start the java virtual machine.

Comment: and unlike jar which is more like a simple archive (like zip and rar) executable cant be decompressed or unzipped

Comment: The great question is: is a JRE included or not?

Comment: If your program appears to be a lot larger than the original jar, then the JRE as been added.

Comment: @leonbloy In case of launch4j, both using a system installed JRE as well as bundling a JRE into the application is possible. Its possible to configure it so that a java application can be installed on a portable disk/usb stick that can be run without installing a JRE on the computer the disk is plugged in to.

Comment: @Shiro this is only true for wrappers, but not for AOT compilers.

Answer (score 0):

These msi and exe files are more like zip file that extract the jar file and it's dependencies and put them in the proper location. They then add shortcuts and links to the files that are needed to start the program.

You can read about it here. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm

and more here.
http://wixtoolset.org/